# .htaccess rewrite rules stops reading url after first part of string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Thank you for reading.

I am trying to rewrite all dynamic category links (/product_list.php?cat_id=xxx)
to more "friendly" text links. The problem I'm running into is with subcategories:

`RewriteRule Complete-AC-Systems product_list.php?cat_id=2`

works great, however when a sub category is present:

`RewriteRule Complete-AC-Systems__Packaged-Systems product_list.php?cat_id=7`

the browser stops reading after Complete-AC-Systems and re-directs to `product_list.php?cat_id=2` not `cat_id=7`

Most of our categories are 3 and 4 levels in, so this is a pervasive issue.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reversing the order of the rules?  I.e., putting the longest matches first.